# How to link objects in different directories in c++ with make without refering to them in the makefile?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I'm trying to clean up my project a little and I want to put object files and include files in a separate folder and be able to compile another makefile in my a different testing subdirectory.  I would like to do this so that the make file in the testing directory doesn't have to know about the objects in the the above directory:  I have been struggling all day trying to figure out make and compilation.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but in addition to this question I would be appreciative of any information to straighten out my thinking about `make` and `g++` so in the future I know where to look.

Anyways I have 2 Questions both with regards to my project layout:

Project

```
inc/
--  header files
-obj/
--object files
-source
-make file for project that compiles objects in obj directory (makefile0)
-testing/
--test1/
---test.cc
---makefile1
```

**Question 1**

So I want to include the header files in the inc directory in test.cc and then just focus on compiling test.cc like I would if I included a standard library header file.  Right now I need to make reference to the object in ../../obj/ in makefile1 and would like to ignore that. and just do something simple like

```
g++ -I ../../inc/ -c test.cc
```

How is it possible to do this?

**Question 2**

In makefile0, for each source file I have to append a $(OBJ) or $(INC) to the front of any file I have in those folders and wondering if there is anyway to clean up my make file an do something like

```
Spinless2DFieldIndex.o: Spinless2DFieldIndex.cc Utils.o Dispersion.h
```

instead of

```
$(ODIR)/Spinless2DFieldIndex.o: Spinless2DFieldIndex.cc $(ODIR)/Utils.o $(INC)/Dispersion.h
```

Comment: Are the executables going to end up in `obj` as well? What about the test objects and test executables? Why does `Spinless2DFieldIndex.o` depend on `Utils.o`?

Comment: No, I want executables in same directory as the makefile that creates them.  It depends on functions defined in Utils.cc. so I want what ever dependencies in Utills.cc to spill over to Spinless2DFieldIndex.o

Comment: The executables will need to link to `Utils.o` but `Spinless2DFieldIndex.o` doesn't, unless it's a shared library but then it shouldn't have the suffix `.o`. So executables are to be placed in `source` and `test1`, what about `test.o`? Or do you just want to skip making the object file for the tests?

Comment: Why doesn't it need to link Spinless2DFieldIndex?  My test executable might use it.  test.o can go in test1 but If my test only has 1 file, I will want to just skip making the object file.

Comment: The whole point about separate compilation is that object files can be compiled independently, only when you link the final executable will `Spinless2DFieldIndex.o` need to know the location of the names in `Utils.o`. I'm guessing the recipe for `Spinless2DFieldIndex.o` ignores everything except the first target (`Spinless2DFieldIndex.cc`) anyway.

Comment: Put another way: why would you want to recompile `Spinless2DFieldIndex.o` every time `Utils.cc` changes? make is designed to avoid these kind of spurious dependencies.

Comment: That makes sense, I knew that deep down but it didn't occur to me that this is where it's important. Thanks.

Comment: Ultimately what you need depends on how separate you need the project components to be, i.e. does it make sense to have separate makefiles in the source and test directories? Do you need to move them out into other projects? Or would it not simply be better to have a single makefile in the root?

Comment: Well Eventually I'm  hoping to turn this into something like a library.  I'm also want to keep my testing files separated since I'm going to be reading the output with python and ploting.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

Project/Makefile

```
objdir := obj/
vpath %.cc source
vpath %.o $(objdir)

CPPFLAGS := -Iinc -MMD -MP

.PHONY: all

all: testing/test1/test

include source/Makefile
include testing/test1/Makefile
```

Project/source/Makefile

```
override objects := $(objdir)obj.o

$(objects): $(objdir)%.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

clean:: ; $(RM) $(objects) $(objects:.o=.d)

-include $(objects:.o=.d)
```

Project/testing/test1/Makefile

```
override dir := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
$(dir)test: obj.o

clean:: ; $(RM) $(dir)test $(dir)test.d

-include $(dir)test.d
```

This should allow for a certain amount of modularity, although the asymmetry in the makefiles betrays the fact that your idea of having a separate `obj` directory while at the same time wanting to have the test executables in their own directory is perhaps not the best way to organize things. Personally I use a more `configure` style of makefile that recreates the project tree in the current working directory which helps separate the source from the build.